# Jquery CLEditor with bootstrap tabs not working

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-tabs, cleditor

I am using jquery [cleditor](http://premiumsoftware.net/cleditor) for `wsyiwyg` editor with `bootstrap tab` in my system. The `textarea` in the first tab is initialized and perfectly working but the `textarea` in second tab is initialized but I cannot type or do anything with it. By the way multiple editors can be used in a single page. What might be the problem with this?

Here is my sample code

```
<!-- Nav tabs -->
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
    <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#home" aria-controls="home" role="tab"
                                              data-toggle="tab">Home</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#profile" aria-controls="profile" role="tab"
                               data-toggle="tab">Profile</a></li>
</ul>

<!-- Tab panes -->
<div class="tab-content">
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="home">
        <textarea name="test" id="test" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
    </div>
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="profile">
        <textarea name="test2" id="test2" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
    </div>
</div>
```

And I initialized the `cleditor` using the following script

```
<script>
    $("textarea").cleditor();
</script>
```

Comment: Did you find the solution? I've got the same problem. It's not working after the first tab

Comment: No luck there mate. I ended up using `tinymce`. It's quite good actually, you can try this too.

Comment: I founded the solution. add this line :
   $('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
        $("iframe").css('width','100%'); //since the problem is the iframe width resize it to 100%, should do the trick 
 
    });